# Reading framerate mode in pymediainfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediainfo

For a while now I have been traverse the world of pymediainfo and attempting to output the 'frame_rate_mode' of a video. Previously I managed to get a printout of either 'Constant' or  'Variable' so I know that I am referencing the correct section of the module, but my 'if' command don't seem to be interacting with it correctly.

My current command just prints nope if the file does not have a 'frame_rate_mode' of 'Constant' and if it does it prints 'yes'. (This is just for testing, eventually I want to pass this onto an ffmpeg command)

The file I am referencing is Constant framerate but I keep receiving a printout of 'nope'. Any help would be appreciated. Code below.

```
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('/Users/ra/Desktop/converts/mhl/50.mov')

for track in media_info.tracks:
    if track.other_frame_rate_mode == 'Constant':
        print ('yes')
        
else:

     print ('nope')
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the contents of `track.other_frame_rate_mode` to see what it contains?

Comment: So in printing `track.other_frame_rate_mode` I did notice it was printed as ['Constant'] which did give me a 'yes' print out but also and 'nope' below which is a contradiction

Comment: Get rid of the empty line between the `else` and the  `print('nope')`.  Also make sure your `else:` and  `print('nope')` are indented properly.